# Ruby combine hashes?

Tags: ruby

Is there a method in ruby to combine two hashes into one? Specifically, given `A = {:a => :b}` and `B = {:b => :c}` I want

```
AB = combine(A,B)
=> {:a => :c}
```

I can make my own if there isn't one in ruby's standard library but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: That merge doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: What happens if you have `A = {:a => :b}`, `B = {:b => :a}`?

Comment: This was a simplified, general case. I'm interested in importing data from a spreadsheet into a rails/redmine environment. I can import the data from the spreadsheet as a list of hashes, mapping column name to value then combine that with a hash mapping a Tracker's field names to excel column names, resulting in a hash mapping Tracker field names to excel column data.

Comment: You can't use a "simplified, general case" to define a problem you want help solving. You have to give us sufficient detail to provide you with a detailed answer. Generic broad questions get broad answers, down voted and then closed. We need to know what you've tried, why it didn't work, or where you've searched and why none of those helped.  Please read "[ask]" and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: What happens if `a = {a: :b}` and `b = {c: :d}`?

Comment: `{ A.keys.first=>B.values.first }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = {:a => :b}
b = {:b => :c}

# Works on ruby >= 2.1
c = a.map{|k, v| [k, b[v]]}.to_h  #=> {:a => :c}

# Works on all versions of ruby
c = Hash[a.map{|k, v| [k, b[v]]}]  #=> {:a => :c}
```